# jquery attr() not working on mobile - Android - Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I'm trying to make an input be enabled/dsabled if an input type text is either empty or not. Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#searchString', function(){
    searchString = $('#searchString');
   if(searchString.val().length > 0){
        $('#cmdSearch').attr('disabled', false);
    }
    else{
        $('#cmdSearch').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

And here is the relevant HTML node:

```
<div class="form-wrapper">
     <form method="post" class="res-form" role="form">
     <input type="text" name="searchString" id="searchString" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="none" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="busca artículos, screencasts o demos">
     <div style="height: 15px;"></div>
     <button type="submit" name="cmdSearch" disabled="true" id="cmdSearch" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success">Buscar</button>
     </form>
</div>
```

It works on desktop, though it doesn't on mobile. Any ideas why?

**EDIT**

I found something interesting, it does work, the problem is, that once I wipe out all the text from the input, let's say the input has a `.val()` of `"foo"` and I delete the `"foo"`, I still have to press `backspace` once more so that the script takes action, this is happening on Android, on Chrome. This seems weird, any fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

For boolean you better use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr()`

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#searchString', function(){
    searchString = $('#searchString');
   if(searchString.val().length > 0){
        $('#cmdSearch').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else{
        $('#cmdSearch').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: edited my post, changed it to what you said, still has the same problem

Comment: Doesn't work on mobile, does on desktop, not on mobile.

Comment: Try using trim $.trim(searchString.val()).length > 0){

Comment: Also try using keypress instead of keyup

Comment: Did you use both trim and keypress?

Comment: Yes, used both of them. Doesn't work. Still have to press backspace on my android keyboard once more so that the input goes disabled.

Comment: What length you get after press backspace on last character?

Comment: I don't think I can get a console.log out of my mobile phone, can I?

Comment: You can use alert() instead I guess

Comment: true, didn't think of that one.

Comment: Ok this is VERY weird. Everytime I press a key on the keyboard, it gives me the number of characters it has right, but everytime I press backspace, it doesn't alert anything, and once the input is empty, and I press backspace once more, then it alerts 0, I have no idea why it behaves like that. :/

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned your new updates, i think you have to use `$.trim()` method to remove any whitespace from that element in the if condition:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#searchString', function(){
    var searchString = $.trim($(this).val()); //<------make a local var instead
    if(searchString > 0){
        $('#cmdSearch').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#cmdSearch').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```