# "AppendTo" href doesn't work in Android Chrome?

Tags: android, jquery, wordpress, google-chrome, append

I have this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  var magyar = $(".lang-item-hu a").attr("href");
  $("#magyar").attr("href", magyar);
  var angol = $(".lang-item-en a").attr("href");
  $("#angol").attr("href", angol);
});
```

on [my site](https://esztervolner.com/). It works well on desktop Chrome, but doesn't work on Android Chrome.

Why? And what could be the remedy for this symptom?

**Question edit/update:**

On my desktop I use the latest version of *Chrome 95.0.4638.69 / 64 bits on Windows 11 Pro ver: 21H2*

On my mobile I also use the currently updated version of *Chrome: 95.0.4638.50 on Android 11, One UI-version: 3.1*

There are no related error messages on the desktop version.

I don't seem to find a debugger on Android's Chrome...

**2nd edit (the solution):**

No, the browser is fine.

I just had to change the `id`-s to `class`es, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  var magyar = $(".lang-item-hu a").attr("href");
  $(".ma").attr("href", magyar);
  var angol = $(".lang-item-en a").attr("href");
  $(".an").attr("href", angol);
});
```

...but I don't quite know why this worked. Anyone who knows leave an answer below. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the browser is fine.

I just had to change the `id`-s to `class`es, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  var magyar = $(".lang-item-hu a").attr("href");
  $(".ma").attr("href", magyar);
  var angol = $(".lang-item-en a").attr("href");
  $(".an").attr("href", angol);
});
```

...but I don't quite know why this worked. Anyone who knows leave an answer below. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One of my suggestion is try with .prop() Instead of .attr()

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  var magyar = $(".lang-item-hu a").attr("href");
  $("#magyar").attr("href", magyar);
  var angol = $(".lang-item-en a").attr("href");
  $("#angol").attr("href", angol);
});
```

Changed to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  var magyar = $(".lang-item-hu a").prop("href");
  $("#magyar").prop("href", magyar);
  var angol = $(".lang-item-en a").prop("href");
  $("#angol").prop("href", angol);
});
```

More Details, pease check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/3073842

Similar Question: [jquery attr() not working on mobile - Android - Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855359/jquery-attr-not-working-on-mobile-android-chrome)

Comment: Thank you, and for your effort I give you an up-vote , but still not working... I'm thinking of cloneing & appendTo-ing at the same time, or simply appending the link, and then styling it.